# Upload files to S3 via Cloudfront

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to upload files to S3 via Cloudfront. I've created a bucket with name my-files. Bucket CORS settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I've created Cloudfront distribution. Here is configuration which can be important:

General:

```
Delivery Method: Web
Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) files.example.com
```

Origins:

```
Origin Domain Name: my-files.s3.amazonaws.com
Restrict Bucket Access: Yes
Grant Read Permissions on Bucket: Yes, Update Bucket Policy
```

Behaviour:

```
Path Pattern: Default (*)
Origin: S3-my-files
Viewer Protocol Policy: HTTP and HTTPS
Allowed HTTP Methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE
Whitelist Headers: Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Origin
Object Caching: Use Origin Cache Headers
Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies): Yes
Trusted Signers: Self
```

I can create signed URL for file download and it works correctly. I can create CNAME for S3 bucket, upload a file to S3 using pre-signed URL and this also works correctly. When I'm trying to upload file via Cloudfront then I'm getting a 403 response (OPTIONS):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://files.example.com/. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://0.0.0.0:5000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Is it possible to use Cloudfront with signed URLs for uploading files? How can I set allowed origins to allow file uploads from localhost?

Comment: did you find out how to do this? - any tutorials you've found useful?

Comment: After uploading te file on s3 did you invalidate file in cloudfront ?

Comment: Any update on this? Did you get this to work - if so how?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that error is relevant with the CORS options of your request.

With jQuery, this is currently my sample code that successfully uploading file to S3 via CloudFront (notice the `crossDomain` option). If you don't use jQuery, you can base on this to write your code:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'YourGetSignatureMethod', //return your signed url
    data: {
          fileName: yourFileName,
          expiration: yourPolicyExpirationDate
    },
    success: function (signedUrl) {
         //signedUrl= 'http://sampleId.cloudfront.net/video.mp4?Policy=examplePolicy&Signature=exampleSignature&Key-Pair-Id=exampleKey'
         let fileObject = yourGetFileFunction(); //returns File API
         let reader = new FileReader(); //using the FileReader API to read files
         reader.onload = function () {                                      
      $.ajax({
  url: signedUrl,
  type: 'PUT',
  contentType: fileObject.type,
  data: reader.result,
  processData: false,
  crossDomain: true,
                success: function(){
                //upload success
                }
     });
        }  
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileObject);
    }
 });
```